# Header tag gets rearranged automatically on website

Tags: html, css, navigation, header, grid-layout

I have created a html page where the header navigation is created on a separate html navigation.html and linked to the index page. While I designed and developed the navigation bar with header tag and run it, its works perfectly and is even totally responsive.

But one I connect the navigation.html to index.html, the header navigation is broken and doesn't work. I tried every fix available and nothings working.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code.
Here's the css file.

```css
header {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #5459ff;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    align-items: center;
}
header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
    margin: 0 0 0 3%;
}
nav {
    margin: 0 6% 0 auto;
    right: 0;
}
.nav_list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav_item {
    margin: 0 8px;
}
.nav a:link,
.nav a:visited,
.nav a:active,
.nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_link {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav_link:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f070;
}
.header_toggle,
.header_close {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        height: 80px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 28px;
    }
    .header_toggle {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 32px;
        color: #f9f070;
    }
    .header_close {
        position: absolute;
        right: 24px;
        color: #f9f070;
        display: block;
        font-size: 32px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -100%;
        margin-right: 0%;
        background-color: #5459ff;
        color: #fff;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 24px 0;
        z-index: 100;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .nav_list {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 30% 10% 0 0;
    }
    .nav_item {
        margin: 30% 0 0 0;
    }
    .show {
        right: 0;
    }
}
.main-page {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000241;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.headp {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr;
}
.headp-head {
    color: #f9f070;
    font-size: 90px;
    font-family: "Secular One", cursive;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: 4% auto auto 6%;
}
.head-desc {
    color: #f9f070;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 50px;
}
.exp-button {
    border: 1px solid #f9f070;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f9f070;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 50px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.headp a:link {
    color: #f9f070;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.headp a:visited {
    color: #f9f070;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.headp a:active {
    color: #f9f070;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.headp a:hover {
    color: #f9f070;
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page</title>
<link href="site.webmanifest" rel="manifest">
<link href="icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
<link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" rel="preconnect">
<link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Secular+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://api.fontshare.com/css?f[]=nippo@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.0/gsap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">
</script>
<script>
 $(function(){
     $("#mainnav").load("navigation.html"); 
     $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-container main-page">
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="cursor"></div>
        <div id="mainnav"></div>
        <div class="headp">
            <div>
                <p class="headp-head">Heading</p>
                <p class="head-desc">Subheading</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js">
    </script> f 
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.8.0.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script>
     window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js" type="module">
    </script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="js/plugins.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="js/main.js">
    </script> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

navigation.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0" name="viewport">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/logo.svg" style="pointer-events: none;"  draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;" alt="logo_main">
        </div>
        <nav class="nav" id="nav-menu">
            <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="header_close" id="close-menu"></ion-icon>
            <ul class="nav_list">
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="" class="nav_link">Link1</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="" class="nav_link">Link2</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="" class="nav_link">Link3</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="" class="nav_link">Link4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <ion-icon name="grid-outline" class="header_toggle" id="toggle-menu"></ion-icon>
    </header>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
const navMenu = document.getElementById("nav-menu"),
    toggleMenu = document.getElementById("toggle-menu"),
    closeMenu = document.getElementById("close-menu");
toggleMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navMenu.classList.toggle("show");
});
closeMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navMenu.classList.remove("show");
});
```

Comment: I’m a bit confused about what you want to do. I don’t understand why you want a complete document inside your other document (even if that were the use of the load function).

Comment: I assumed it would be easier for me to edit the navigation once I have too many pages, as I intent to create a website with more than 10 pages.

I did the same with my footer and it's working completely fine.